# UsersRole table is not working correctly while using config.excluded models in apartment of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

User and Role is working in global while using config.excluded_models in apartment.rb, but UsersRole model is not working. If any tenant is logged in, I want to display  all the users and roles

```
  config.excluded_models = %w{ User Role UsersRole}
```

I am using devise and rolify gem for users and roles. Then i have created the new model UsersRole (manually). It works without tenant concept. But I need to implement with tenants.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 rolify
end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

    belongs_to :resource,
            :polymorphic => true,
            :optional => true


    validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

    scopify
end
```

Comment: can u paste the code of user, role and userRole models here?

Comment: Can you please add some codes?

Comment: I am using devise and rolify gem for users and roles. Then i have created the new model UsersRole (manually). It works without tenant concept. But I need to implement with tenants. @nileshkumar

Comment: do you work with apartment gem in rails @MichałSzkudlarek

Comment: This works me.  user.rb                                                                                                      rolify role_join_table_name: 'default_dabase_name.users_roles'